# Open Remote Network Folder with Permissions

Tags: networking, permissions, directory

I'm trying to open up an Explorer window of a remote folder and need to supply a username and password??? Please help because the net.exe use option does not seem to work. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an FTP account. That's all I can tell you given the info you provided.

Answer (score 0):

net.exe don't do this kind of stuff, net.exe just tell you info about computers on the net

1- If you just want remote access of a folder within a LAN not the remote access of your whole computer you should say the Operational System you want to access and the Operational System you're using to access this remote folder for the question to be answered.

2- If you want remote desktop access you should use TeamViewer or on windows the Remote Desktop application.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-nz/windows-vista/Connect-to-another-computer-using-Remote-Desktop-Connection

The advantage of TeamViewer like softwares is the facility of using it whenever you are, on LAN or Internet.